# How to move from modal to another navigation controller?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a navi-controller(A) with buttons.

As a button, a modalview(B) appears.

In modalview(B) I can access a button to move another navigation Controller(C).

How can I code?

Comment: You shouldn't just ask for the code, plus this is extremely basic stuff which can be found in apple documentation/Google.

Comment: I agree with @LuisOscar, if you can't figure this on your own, you should be working on something simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can dismiss a UIViewController that was displayed modally before displaying another UIViewController. Or you can display another UIViewController on top of the first view controller. `self.navigationController` will probably be useful.

Answer (score 0):

try this to open a new modal for both the modal  set this action for the buttons you want.
    -(IBAction)btnAddNewPressed:(id)sender
{
  ViewController *s= [[ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
  [self presentModalViewController:student animated:YES];

}